# How to Load Live youtube url link to webview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i try many times to load Live youtube url but i am not sure why there are not working.

Note:-  youtube url works fine on webbrowser i can implement same as on iphone. so please help me.

Query:-  The url is open in webview but not streaming & giving me the current live sceen. i can see live darshan on webbrowser but in my app i can't see live it's just pause screen.

Please check below code which i can use.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
         NSString *strUrl=@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/"; // this is live darshan url
        [self embedYouTube:strUrl frame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 300, 300)];
    }

- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {

    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <!DOCTYPE html><html><head>\
    <style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; background:#1111}</style>\
    </head><body><div id=\"player\"></div>\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    videoView.delegate = self;
    videoView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=YES;
    videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.0];
    videoView.opaque= NO;
    [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
    [self.view addSubview:videoView];
}
```

Comment: use ytplayer https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

Comment: there is error on code . so this is not help me. @JaiminPatel